# My elasticsearch queries crush each other

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, multisearchresponse

I try to write a search method with elasticsearchClient Here is my method:

```
`@Override
public Iterable<ElasticCompany> find(String category) {
    try {
        SearchResponse<ElasticCompany> response = null;

        response = elasticsearchClient.search(s -> s
                        .index("company_elastic_idx")
                        .query(q -> q
                                .fuzzy(t -> t
                                        .field("company.category")
                                        .fuzziness("auto")
                                        .value(category)
                                )
                        ).query(q -> q
                                .fuzzy(t -> t
                                        .field("company.name")
                                        .fuzziness("auto")
                                        .value(category))),
                ElasticCompany.class
        );

        List<ElasticCompany> elasticCompanyList = new ArrayList<>();
        response.hits().hits().forEach(hit -> elasticCompanyList.add(hit.source()));

        return elasticCompanyList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}`
```

This is my elasticsearchClient bean:

```
`@Bean
public RestClient restClient(){
    return RestClient
            .builder(HttpHost.create(elasticsearchUrl))
            .setDefaultHeaders(new Header[]{})
            .build();
}`
```

I want to search by two fields in the index but my second query crush second one. How can i create a SearchResponse to search by two fiends?

I want to try a write method whict is searcing two fields and return all my company list.